# Use SVG in pseudo element content or background image in Vue template file

Tags: css, vue.js

I don't know how I can use a SVG file as a pseudo content element in Vue template files.

In the scoped CSS of my Vue template file (`Select.vue`) I have:

```
.wrap {
  &:after {
    content: url("../../assets/icons/caret-down-solid.svg");
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  }
}
```

the path is relative of the components location. But it does not simply show up.

Things I have tried and noticed:

- I have tried without the `" "` around the URL too.
- I have tried using a `background-image` and `content: " "` instead, didn't work either.
- **It *works* with an absolute URL (for example a testfile on the web)**
- It does resolve the local URL in my example because when I do `../../../asserts/icons/caret-down-solid.svg` to take a wrong path it will fail compiling.

So it looks like the  file gets resolved, the syntax is correct, but it does not show up for whatever reason.

**Edit:** When inspecting the pseudo element while using `background-image` I see:

`background-image: url([object Module]);`

Comment: How does this scoped CSS render? Is that something vue puts directly into the page source, or does it get loaded via an external stylesheet? (Relative paths in external stylesheets are relative to the location of the stylesheet.)

Comment: @misorude It is not that, as you can see in my edit it tries to load the link as a module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case someone comes across this question I managed to solve this.
Problem was that the `vue-svg-loader` I was using was importing the `.svg` file as a module. So I had to use an `svg-url-loader` for importing svgs into styles.

In my `vue.config.js` under the `chainWebpack` option I was adding:

```
config.module.rule("svg")
  .oneOf("inline")
    .resourceQuery(/inline/)
    .use("svg-url-loader")
      .loader("svg-url-loader")
      .end()
    .end()
  .oneOf("external")
    .use("vue-svg-loader")
      .loader("vue-svg-loader");
```

what this does is when you append a `?inline` to your svg it will treat it with a different loader (`svg-url-loader` in this case)

So in the CSS you do:

```
.wrap {
  &:after {
    content: url("../../assets/icons/caret-down-solid.svg?inline");
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  }
}
```

and it will import the SVG properly inline.